# My popup angular it is closing when save something

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have created a popup but also I have make a button to save something and there is button declared if the length of ID is greater than 0 than I can continue working, but everytime it is exiting my popup.

I think the reason that it is closing the popup its the service matrix row it is under component from the service matrix and in the matrix row it is called the component like popup.

```
   <app-service-matrix-row *ngFor="let valueItem of products$ | async" [valueItem]="valueItem"   [hidden]="!((filteredProductIds$ | async).includes(valueItem.id)) || !(isProduct$ | async)"></app-service-matrix-row>
```

In the service matrix row

I have called that component like popup

```
<app-edit-dialog-vi  *ngIf="showChild" [data]="dataToPass" [(activeSelected)]="activeSelected" [(showMePartially)]="showChild"></app-edit-dialog-vi>

dataToPass: any = null;
 showChild = false;
 activeSelected: any = '';
```

But everytime when I save something in this popup the popup it is closed.

This is the code in the popup.

```
 @Input() showMePartially: boolean;
  @Output() showMePartiallyChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Input() activeSelected: boolean;
  @Output() activeSelectedChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Input() data: EditViOptions = null;
  @Input() active: boolean;

<div *ngIf="showMePartially" class="container">

</div>
<button *ngIf="editedValueItem.id.length > 0" (click)="save()">{{'button.#save'|translate}} & {{'button.#continue'|translate}}</button>
<button (click)="save()">{{'button.#save'|translate}}</button>
<button (click)="cancel()">{{'button.#cancel'|translate}}</button>


this.store.dispatch(new InsertValueItemAction(this.editedValueItem));

 if (this.editOptions.valueItem) {
  if (this.editedValueItem.type === ValueItemType.SERVICE || this.editedValueItem.type === ValueItemType.PRODUCT) {
    let list: string[] = [];
    list.push(this.editedValueItem.businessId);
    this.store.dispatch(new SetIdFilterAction(list));
  }
}

/* Here is when the child is appended to parent or is edited */
this.store.dispatch(new ExpandRowAction(this.editOptions.appendToParentId));
```

Comment: create stackblitz example here ---> https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: it will take me 2-3 days to create a stackblitz because I am not good in stackblitz